# Excel and database

Tags: excel, function

I have a table like this:

[image]

and another table that is in **another file** like this:

[image]

I'd like to create a function to "copy" value in the column B (from the first page) in the corresponding field on the second page. Column A/B values in the two pages have to match.
The result will be this (in page2):

```
   A   |   B
-------|-------
house1 | 
elem1  | 100
house2 | 
elem2  | 101
house3 | 
elem3  | 102
```

How can I do? I don't know how to do..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this that way:
On sheet2 in cell B1 add the following formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE),"")` and paste it down - change the `Sheet1` to you sheet name (page1?)

Comment: what is the name of your page1 sheet?

Comment: If your sheet name has spaces in it you should put the name of the sheet in single quotes '', for example: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'TestSheet 1'!A:B,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: To use it with between workbooks use this: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\[Book2.xlsm]TestSheet 1'!A:B,2,FALSE),"")` where Book2.xlsm is you book name with page1 data. Don't forget to change the path to your file as well

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work, I tried:  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'/Users/me/Desktop/[Page2.xlsx]Foglio1'!A:B,2,FALSE),"") but nothing

Comment: Change `/Users/me/Desktop/[Page2.xlsx]Foglio1` to `C:\Users\me\Desktop\[Page2.xlsx]Foglio1` if "C" is your system drive

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `Sheet1` and you want result in `Sheet2` then try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,0)),"")
```

Here, `Sheet2!A1` is being searched in `Sheet1!A1:B3` for match.

For different files try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('File_Path[File_Name.xls]Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$3,MATCH(A1,'File_Path[File_Name.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$3,0)),"")
```

**File_Path** should be the path where your file is. Like: `C:\test\`.
**File_Name** should be name if the file where your data for comparison is: Like `MyFile`.
Here, `Sheet1!A1:B3` contains data to be matched and `Cell A1` text to be matched.

Enter this formula in `Cell B1` and drag it down.

Comment: I have two different excel files..Can you suggest something please? Thanks